# Decode encoded data in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, encryption

I was using "mcrypt-*" for decoding the response in previous PHP 5.6 version but now in PHP 7.2 version as it is deprecated I am using openSSL method. But it is not working properly hopefully I am missing something.

```
$value="###lllljG5ZOibDGtlL gcQLAtTQUnCJ/bE2glWsL1WKVPdC22c9GtGe/Npx9Uv9IYaszOAVXB4T9s7Hsss/2XpZ9oisx5M4jeV7RK2S/JrBt2E4GEcDGwuJs6NhkKV8hdOcU tmkJLxO3OJ OgVbqrT6a4v5RE7w eP zvQwZyAR5cYCKUYomou9mL/pvfLbe RrBe5ZnMQmUrD6cwUxEE/inikMvIb4K7HI fVPid N B3iPnIYQna6/v9W5A0kslBj6BBDjVXJabwmCSDVxbArm0GDNseWoQAEa4BMxYitqP6cVTxL5Kri8xbAKCW5/unnYnudkHQjNJWW7LuiwDxsBqwQv8D/R/Ff/joFW6q0 muI16/CfIoFnYAyAJWNlKCX9";

    $value = urldecode($value);
    $value = str_replace(" ", "+", $value);

    $abc = triple_decrypt($value);
    print_r($abc);
```

PHP 5.6 working fine

```
function triple_decrypt($input){
    $key = "thisis87658748639testkey";
    $input = base64_decode($input);
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TripleDES, "", MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, "");
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $pwd = trim(mdecrypt_generic($td, $input), "\x00..\x0F");
    mcrypt_generic_end($td);
    return $pwd;
}
```

PHP 7.2

```
function triple_decrypt($input){
    $key = "thisis87658748639testkey";
    $cipher = "des-ede3";
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $pwd = openssl_decrypt($input, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
    return $pwd;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*openssl* uses PKCS7-padding and *mcrypt* Zero-padding [[0]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#117208)[[1]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php)[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)). To decrypt the ciphertext with *openssl*, *openssl*'s padding must be disabled and *mcrypt*'s Zero-padding bytes must be removed:

```
function triple_decrypt($input){
    $key = "thisis87658748639testkey";
    $cipher = "des-ede3";
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($input, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING); // Disable openssl's PKCS7-padding
    $unpadded = trim($decrypted, "\x00..\x0F");                                         // Remove mcrypt's Zero-padding bytes
    return $unpadded;
}
```

---

However, note the following with regard to a *reimplementation* of encryption and decryption: ECB is an insecure mode [[3]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946). Instead, CBC or even better GCM should be used [[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). Instead of Triple-DES the modern and faster todays standard AES is recommended [[6]](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181). Zero-padding is unreliable, PKCS7-padding should be applied instead.

---

Furthermore, the *mcrypt* code is to some extent inconsistent:

- The ECB mode doesn't use an IV (this is also the reason why `openssl_cipher_iv_length` returns `0` in the *openssl* code [[7]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php)). `mcrypt_generic_init` ignores the IV in case of the ECB mode [[8]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic-init.php), so it's not used in the *mcrypt* code and therefore not needed in the *openssl* code.
- And if a mode would be used that requires an IV, then the following would have to be considered: The IV is always needed for encryption *and* decryption. Therefore, a random IV is generated (and used) during encryption and then *passed on* to the recipient together with the ciphertext, where it's used for decryption. Since the IV isn't secret, it's usually prefixed to the ciphertext. The generation of a random IV *during decryption* therefore makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `openssl()`

```
function encryptIt($q) {

 $cryptKey  = 'YourProjectname'; //any string

 $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC"; 
 $secretHash = "25c6c7rr35b9979b151f0205cd13b0vv"; // any hash

//To encrypt
 $qEncoded = openssl_encrypt($q, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash);

 return $qEncoded;

}

function decryptIt($q) {

 $cryptKey = 'YourProjectname'; //any string
 $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC"; 
 $secretHash = "25c6c7rr35b9979b151f0205cd13b0vv"; // any hash


//To Decrypt
 $qDecoded = openssl_decrypt($q, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash);

 return $qDecoded;

}

$encryptedstring = encryptIt('TEST');
echo "<br/>";
echo decryptIt($encryptedstring);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Actually i have mentioned a value($value) which already in decode format. I need to encode that. I am able to encode and decode new string.

Comment: ` $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);` it is return 0 length. For most of common AES cipher modes (CBC,CFB,ECB,OFB) the IV length should be 128 bits = 16 bytes.

Comment: Am I put anything wrong or any issue in encrypted value?

Comment: change your `$cipher = "des-ede3";` value

Comment: changed $cipher value to "AES-256-CBC" but not getting the decode value as expected. strange symbol coming in o/p.

Comment: you also need to change $cipher value to "AES-256-CBC" when encrypt string.

Comment: @Tushar add your encrypt string function in question.

Comment: I think the OP wants to decrypt a ciphertext with the *openssl* code, whereas this ciphertext was *once* encrypted with the *mcrypt* code. Therefore it makes no sense to change the algorithm / mode. Of course a change would make sense for a reimplementation of *both*, encryption and decryption, as AES is faster and more modern and ECB is generally insecure.